# SQL show where value is current user or column value of current user

Tags: sql, join, multiple-results

Currently I am working on a project, and I got stuck to show my results.
Please can someone help me out.

I have two tables, Jobs and Employees

```
Jobs                                     Employees
| JobID    | JobDescr | EmployeeID |     | EmpID    | EmpName  | EmpSub     |
| -------- | -------- | ---------- |     | -------- | -------- | ---------- |
| 1        | Job text | 0005       |     | 0001     | Name 1   | 0003       |
| 2        | Job text | 0008       |     | 0002     | Name 2   | 0004       |
| 3        | Job text | 0003       |     | 0003     | Name 3   | 0001       |
| 4        | Job text | 0004       |     | 0004     | Name 4   | 0004       |
| 5        | Job text | 0001       |     | 0005     | Name 5   | 0001       |
```

I want to show the job results of the current user (EmID 0001) and his substitute.

```
Results of current user (EmpID 0001)
| JobID    | JobDescr | EmpName |
| -------- | -------- | ------- |
| 1        | Job text | Name 5  |
| 3        | Job text | Name 3  |
| 5        | Job text | Name 1  |
```

This is what I tried so far

```
SELECT JobID, JobDescr e.EmpName FROM Jobs 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees AS e ON Jobs = EmployeeID
WHERE EmployeeID = {USERID} AND ... 
ORDER BY JobID, EmployeeID
```

How to continue?
Please help and thanks!

Comment: Your sample data is inconsistent. 0008 is not found in Employees. (Or is it the empsub value EmployeeID references?)

Comment: What is USERID? where is it coming from? It feels like this is missing information.
This is a trivial join, but where are you defining what a USERID is? Also, you're not going to output any field from the e table.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want jobs by a particular user and by their subs, you can use UNION ALL to combine two queries. This isn't the only way to do it, but it's clean.

```
select * from jobs where employeeid = {USERID}
union all
select * from jobs where employeeid IN (SELECT empsub FROM employees where empid = {USERID})
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality
Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some
guidelines for [How do I write a good
answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are
**not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted
because they are less useful to a community of learners. Please [edit] your
answer to include an explanation of how and why the code solves the problem,
when it should be used, what its limitations are, and if possible a link to
relevant documentation.